# mqtt protocol vs webRTC

Tags: xmpp, real-time, webrtc, instant-messaging, mqtt

What is mqtt and webRTC?

Where can I use them if I am developing a NATIVE mobile web application which supports voice and video chat?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suitable protocol for Instant Messaging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464820/suitable-protocol-for-instant-messaging)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. Questions of recommendation or "vs" nature are usually off-topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Flow Thanks for the comment. Just edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing two different things.

MQTT is a messaging protocol for publish/subscribe that you could use to implement the communication between your native application and the back-end servers.

WebRTC is a standard that modern web browsers are beginning to support to allow a pure web application (HTML5/JavaScript/CSS3) to implement voice and video interaction without requiring any browser plugins (typically today such implementations require the use  of Flash). Its worth pointing out that support in native browsers for webRTC is only now emerging (and still not supported on iOS). If you were developing a mobile web application you might choose to use webRTC to support voice and video in a platform independent way and then use MQTT over web sockets to implement the communications to the server.

Since you are developing a NATIVE mobile application, webRTC is not really relevant. As a native application you are not constrained by browser support.

Comment: Well, Many thanks!!! You cleared many things.
There is still one question that might be silly:
So as our application is native webRTC is cancelled out. Now MQTT is left. So can an app like above be developed using MQTT ONLY? Or do we have to include a protocol like XMPP? Asking this because you wrote "MQTT is a messaging protocol for publish/subscribe that you could use to implement the communication between your native application and the back-end servers."

Comment: Yes, you could choose either mqtt or XMPP as the communication protocol as I said over on your other post:  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464820/suitable-protocol-for-instant-messaging). If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it so I get the reputation. Thanks.