# Does it make sense using http POST requests for instant messaging app

Tags: ajax, post, request

I will work on a messaging system. I wonder if it overuses the Server when Client sends requests to sql every minutes to check if there is a new messages? If it doesn't make sense, what is the most sensible way of achieving this?

Comment: Short answer, no. Check out question though. XMPP seems to be popular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464820/suitable-protocol-for-instant-messaging